# Image not being set on custom UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

So I am trying to create a circular navbar button in my app that holds a users image. I went the route of subclassing UIButton and creating my own custom class.

All is well except for the part where I try to grab the image. I use alamofire to get the image based off of the URL that i get from firebase however the button is blue? with no image

Have I done anything wrong in my code

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import AlamofireImage
import Alamofire

class CircularNavButton: UIButton {
    var userHandle: DatabaseHandle = 0
    var userRef: DatabaseReference?


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @objc func setupView(){
        observeUser()
    }


    @objc func observeUser(){
        self.userHandle = UserService.observeProfile(for: User.current, completion: { (userRef, user, nil) in
            self.userRef = userRef
            guard let userProfilePic = user?.profilePic else{
                return
            }
            Alamofire.request(userProfilePic).responseImage { response in
                debugPrint(response)
                if let image = response.result.value {
                    self.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                    print("image downloaded: \(image)")
                }
            }
        })
    }

    deinit {
        userRef?.removeObserver(withHandle: userHandle)

    }

}
```

Below is the init for when I add it to my navbar

```
 @objc func setupCircularNavButton(){
    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "sports").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

    let customView = CircularNavButton(type: .system)
    customView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showMenu), for: .touchUpInside)
    customView.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleToFill

    customView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    customView.clipsToBounds = true

    customView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.insert(barButtonItem, at: 0)
}
```

Comment: sure user has a profile , also does **print("image downloaded: \(image)"** is printed ??

Comment: Is `observeUser` being called? Is the Alamofire request being made?

Comment: yes the request is being made @rmaddy

Comment: everything is printed and all calls are being made @Sh_Khan

Comment: can you make the barbutton&& custom button  instance variables and try ??

Comment: also do **self.superView?.setNeedsDisplay()** inside the button after you set the image in the callback

Comment: nope still blue for some reason @Sh_Khan and would making it an instance variable change anything?

Comment: i said try .............

Comment: nope nothing changed @Sh_Khan

Comment: may be the problem is in the fact that it's inside a barbutton try to add it to as subview to self.view and try , also give it a frame or set translateautoresising to false with constraints

Comment: I tried that already and introducing the frame just causes a whole different problem @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix this issue by setting my button type to custom when I initialized it like so

```
    let customView = CircularNavButton(type: .custom)
```